# FTDI I2C libMPSSE

Tags: c, i2c

I'm working on reading flow rates from a sensrion lg16 flow rate sensor using a USB FTDI I2C dongle. I have all the wiring done and I am able to write to it and verify I am able to write to it correctly using an oscilloscope with an I2C analyzer. My problem is when i try to do a read from the sensor, even when reading to a register after writing to it i dont get missing Acks on the I2C bus.

here my code to read the register i want to see at the moment

```
bytesToTransfer=0;
bytesTransfered=0;
buffer[bytesToTransfer++]=0xE5; 
//buffer[bytesToTransfer++]= 0x7f;
status = I2C_DeviceWrite(ftHandle, slaveAddress, bytesToTransfer, buffer, \
    &bytesTransfered,   I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_START_BIT|I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_STOP_BIT | I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_FAST_TRANSFER_BYTES);
printf("bytestxd=%d\n",bytesTransfered);
printf("status=%d\n",status);
APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
```

Comment: So the device doesn't ACK the read command that you verify is there?

Comment: Please explain "I don't get missing Acks".  Do you mean you see no evidence of missing acks (the acks are there), or are you actually missing acks but accidentally typed a double negative?  Clarity is important.

Comment: lol sorry, i will clearify. from what i understand when doing a read the I2C master is reponsabile for the Acks, which i am seeing on the scope waveform but the scope I2C analyzer sais im not getting an Ack. im getting responses from the read command and print them out to the terminal but they are just random numbers that have nothing to do with the actual flow rate im applying

Comment: im a little concerened this behavior is due to a 100 ns pulste on the clock lign directly before the Ack is expected, and ideas what might be causing that?

Comment: I've encountered stuff like this before, because reads on I2C are much more finicky than writes. My intuition would be that you're not properly implementing the read command format for the particular device OR you're trying to read registers that aren't readable via an I2C command.

Comment: ok so it looks like the oscilloscope I'm using is just way more sensitive than the ftdi dongle